# How to use api variable in a link WITHOUT use of PHP

Tags: javascript, html, json, video

I need to embed a youtube video on to my webpage. When a user clicks on a movie title link, it takes them to a movie details page. This movie detail page uses `TheMovieDB API` and I am able to output the description and movie title of the movie clicked on to my page using just the `movieid` to pull the information.

The problem I am having is trying to embed the correct youtube video, the video ID is being pulled correctly from `themoviedb` page but I am not sure how to use it in the url.

This is for a class so I am not allowed to use php for this assignment (only store the movieid in my database and then need to pull the description, title and video from themoviedb using API). I am only having trouble with the video.

```js
<script>
    let getConfig = function () {
            let url =' https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/<?=$_GET['mid']?>?api_key=<APIKEY>&append_to_response=videos';
            fetch(url)
            .then((result)=>{
                return result.json();
            })
            .then((data)=>{
                 console.log('config:', data);
                console.log('config fetched');
            //process the returned data
              document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = (data.title);
              document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (data.overview);
              document.getElementById('yt').innerHTML = (data.videos.results[0].key);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                alert(err);
            });
        }

</script>
```

`data.videos.results[0].key` is where the video id is and I am able to pull it correctly when i use the following code in my html *(note the yt id is different depending on what movie link is clicked).*

```html
<html>
<div id ="title"></div> //correctly prints out the title of movie clicked
<div id="output"></div> //correctly prints out the description of movie clicked
<div id = "yt"></div> //correctly prints out the youtube video id of movie clicked
</html>
```

So I know I have the right video id coming from the API, the problem is embedding the youtube video url to contain this id at the end for example I tried this in my html:

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<span id="yt"></span>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

A blank video gets embedded that I cannot play and when I go to the url of the video it shows this; https://www.youtube.com/embed/%3Cspan%20id%20=

(Note: when I use the span tag in the src, I make sure to delete the div tag using the `yt` id before since the id can not be used twice)

How can I make it so my youtube video id gets added to the end of the src url, like this `https://www.youtube.com/embed/zbZoTOTUZ14`.

I need the id after **`/embed`** but I do not know how to put it in the url without the use of `PHP`.

(I am sorry if this is too long, I am new here and will improve on how to ask questions.)

Maybe the youtube video needs to be embedded in the script and not html but I am not sure.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: no there are none, it gives me the data and then says config fetched